# Openweathermap: No response via python, but there is responce via APItester

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a little Code in python in order to get the current weather from https://openweathermap.org/. However, when I run my Code, I get the error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\app\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\app\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\app\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\app\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\app\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/2.5/weather?appid=298b44e1966f7870841309311c2988e9&q=London (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000024DB4CD9710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]"
```

If I send the same request via https://apitester.com/, then my URL works, i.e. I get a json-file back with weather informations. So I assume something is wrong with my python Code or Windows cannot handle it:

```
import requests

def get_weather():
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=298b44e1966f787084fftrhbbgzzum&q=London"
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()   
def main():
    weather = get_weather()
    print(weather)   

main()
```

Comment: Try testing without the spaces after the `?`

Comment: oh, sorry, I've just posted it a bit wrong here...now corrected :)

Comment: The code looks fine, I assume you are using a different id as I get an `Invalid API key`. Are you behind some kind of firewall/proxy?

Comment: Thank you! So it is probably really the security of our Company...